# Any possibilities of building an universal login system with Microsoft App registrations?

Tags: php, azure, authentication

Basically, the title says it all.

More & more students at our school are asking for a way to authenticate through our Microsoft environment for their own school projects/web applications.

So, we are willing to listen to that and build an universal login system. We need a system (preferably with an App registration in the Azure portal) that allows logins to Microsoft on our organization. Then, after logging in, we want it to redirect to any students site (on the same domain) and authenticate to that.

Important to note, most of the students use PHP for their web applications. The use of the Graph API is not required, but would be cool.

So, is there any possibility for that? If so, how would we do that?

Comment: You mean you want a php based component that students can add to their applications? Naturally, that's possible, yes, as it would be in any web programming language

Comment: @ADyson Yeah pretty much, think of it as a generic system, hosted at for example: login.school.edu. Students can then link that system to their own site at, for example: student194.school.edu.
So they have to be able to log in to another website, and then they are authenticated on their own website, through Microsoft

Comment: Right. Well that's a bit of a broad topic for a stackoverflow post really, it's a whole project. What exactly do you want from us? Have you got  a more specific request? See also [ask]

Comment: @ADyson Sorry. I'm just looking for someone who can explain the concept of how it works & how it could be build. Nothing code-related.

Comment: Well that's pretty broad and vague too. Where would we be starting from, knowledge-wise? Are you familiar with things like OAuth, for example? Have you read all the relevant MS documentation on how their login system works? Have you checked whether anyone has maybe made such a component already, or at least some php code which could go towards it? Etc etc.  We don't know what you dont know, if you see what I mean

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/identity/add-sign-in-with-microsoft should be your starting point

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=micosoft+identity+php also looks promising

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the above requirement You will need to modify your `PHP web application` code to redirect to your any students site post authentication with Azure AD.

Thus to authenticate with Azure AD you will need to include the ***Azure AD Authentication*** assembly in your `pHp website code` . For example you can refer this [***GitHub sample***](https://gist.github.com/DragonBe/8af1044185ef14e61cd98e6086e3fc59)

Once the above has been done then you will need to [***register an application in  AzureAD***](https://katystech.blog/projects/php-azuread-oauth-login#:%7E:text=To%20create%20the%20App%20Registration,.name%2Foauth.php.) for your `php webapplication` and configure the web application redirect url and call back url accordingly .
[image]

Further you will need to add redirection uri for the student websites in the `php webapplication` code itself and ensure that the student websites are hosted as subdomain website for the `php web application` itself.

For more information please refer this ***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***:- [***Integrating with the Microsoft identity platform***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-how-to-integrate)